# Time/Date real time plot in R

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, rstudio, real-time

I want to plot some data in real-time against time.

The code I am using is very similar to this, taken from another answer I read on here:

```
n=1000
df=data.frame(time=1:n,y=runif(n))
window=100
for(i in 1:(n-window)) 
{
    flush.console()
    plot(df$time,df$y,type='l',xlim=c(i,i+window))
    Sys.sleep(0.1)
}
```

I would like to plot the time on the x-axis of the graph. So I did this:

```
n=1000
df=data.frame(time=0,y=runif(n))
window=100
for(i in 1:(n-window)) 
{

    **df$time[i] <- format(Sys.time(),"%X")**

    flush.console()
    plot(df$time,df$y,type='l',xlim=c(i,i+window))
    Sys.sleep(0.1)
}
```

But I get errors, do any of you have any help/ advice

Many thanks,

Ben

**EDIT**

I want this to run 900 times, at a set frequency. Could I calculate the time values ahead of the for loop.  e.g.

df$DateTime[1] = Sys.time()

FOR(;;)
df$DateTime[i] = df$DateTime[i] + X seconds
END FOR LOOP

FOR(;;)
//// simulate live plotting ?
END FOR LOOP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To plot the time, you need a time object. I modified your code a bit to actually have a time vector. Also, I change the way you indexed the vector to get rid of the `xlim`.

```
n=1000
df=data.frame(time=Sys.time()+1:n,y=runif(n))
window=100
for(i in 1:(n-window))
{
    flush.console()
    df1 <-df[i:(i+window),]
    plot(df1$time,df1$y,type='l')
    Sys.sleep(0.1)
}
```

**EDIT** Solution to add hours. You can add hours but it seems to slow down the process. As you can see, I added the `axis.POSIXct` call, but I had to slow down the `Sys.Sleep` to 0.5 and you can barely see the x-axis:

```
n=1000
df=data.frame(time=Sys.time()+1:n,y=runif(n))
window=100
for(i in 1:(n-window))
{
    flush.console()
    df1 <-df[i:(i+window),]
    x_at <-pretty(df1$time)
    x_labels <-format(pretty(df1$time),"%H:%M:%S")
    plot(df1$time,df1$y,type='l',xaxt='n')
    axis.POSIXct(side=1,at=x_at,labels=x_labels)
    Sys.sleep(0.5)
}
```

Comment: Awesome thank you ever so much! Is there a way I can get the time to display as HH:MM:SS?

Comment: Great! Thank you :D

Comment: What takes a long time to execute is the `axis.POSIXct` not the calculation.